# Fast way to multiply a large list of lists with another list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

1. I'm trying to find a set of values w,x,y,z that give me maximum
   value of **L** such that w+x+y+z=1.
2. First I'm taking all the possible combinations of x,w,y and z into 
   list **values** and then I'm multiplying each set of combination with 
   probList.
3. The sum of each list of probList is taken and multiplied together and 
   appended to L.Then L is sorted to find the highest value.This is my code:

   ```
   import itertools
   import numpy as np
   x_dim=np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
   y_dim=np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
   z_dim=np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
   i=0
   values=[]
   L=[]
   I=[]
   maxI=defaultdict(dict)
   for w, x, y in itertools.product(x_dim, y_dim, z_dim):
       s=w+x+y
           if s<1:
               z=1-s
               values.append([w,x,y,z])
   for params in values:
       new_pList=probList*params  
       L.append(np.prod(np.sum(new_pList, axis=1)))
       I.append([w,x,y,z])
   k=0
   for item in L:
       maxI[item]=I[k]
       k+=1
   maxI=sorted(maxI.items(), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
   print(maxI[0:5])
   ```

This seems to take a lot of time as len(probList) is

> 103665

The structure of probList is (103665 x 4) and looks like this:

```
[[  1.0  1.0   8.6   1.7]
 [  5.0   5.0   5.0   8.8] 
 [  1.0   1.0   1.0   2.6] 
 ...,   
 [  1.0   1.0   8.3  ]
 [  1.0   1.0   5.3   1.8]
 [  1.0   5.0   4.6   7.]]
```

The structure of w_dim,x_dim,z_dim is:

```
[ 0.    0.01  0.02  0.03  0.04  0.05  0.06  0.07  0.08  0.09  0.1   0.11
  0.12  0.13  0.14  0.15  0.16  0.17  0.18  0.19  0.2   0.21  0.22  0.23
  ......
  0.84  0.85  0.86  0.87  0.88  0.89  0.9   0.91  0.92  0.93  0.94  0.95
  0.96  0.97  0.98  0.99]
```

The structure of Values is:

```
 [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.98999999999999999],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.02, 0.97999999999999998],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.029999999999999999, 0.96999999999999997], 
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.040000000000000001, 0.95999999999999996]
 [.....
 [0.96999999999999997, 0.02, 0.0, 0.010000000000000009], 
 [0.97999999999999998, 0.0, 0.0, 0.020000000000000018], 
 [0.97999999999999998, 0.0, 0.01, 0.010000000000000009], 
 [0.97999999999999998, 0.01, 0.0, 0.010000000000000009], 
 [0.98999999999999999, 0.0, 0.0, 0.010000000000000009]]
```

Please suggest me a more optimised way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use matrix dot?

```
w_dim=np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01).reshape(-1,1)
x_dim=np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01).reshape(-1,1)
y_dim=np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01).reshape(-1,1)
W = np.concatenate([w_dim, x_dim, y_dim], axis=1)
z = np.maximum(1 - np.sum(W, axis=1, keepdims=True), 0)

params = np.concatenate([W,z], axis=1)
result = probList * params

result_sum = np.sum(result, axis=1)
idx = result_sum.argsort()[::-1]
output = result[idx,:]
```

Comment: w, x and y should  have **(100*100*100)** combinations, but yours seem to take only 100. And also I'm getting `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (103665,4) (100,4) `. Can you please suggest me what to do.

Comment: @Meghanab could you give all your variable shape?

Comment: @Meghanab My solution is OK for your demand. You just need to construct appropriate `W` matrix. The other part is applicative.